# проблемы с bat'ником при запске через планировщик windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cmd, bat, планировщик-задач

Запускаю bat через планировщик Windows 10 и через раз файл не исполняется, при этом заголовок консоли меняется с адреса к батнику на SELECT и дальше адрес батника. Пробовал делать запуск не при входе в систему, а с задержкой 30 сек, но не помогло.

P.S. в bat запускается локальный питон cgi сервер, проблема бывает только при запуске через планировщик

Вот строки bat-файла:

```
e:
cd E:\Pro\Python\server
python dvig.py
```

Comment: Хоть бы пример кода привели (батник). Вопрос очень абстрактный. Требует доработки.

Comment: 3 строчки e:
cd E:\Pro\Python\server
python dvig.py

Comment: А не проще сразу прописать все сразу в одной строке? python E:\Pro\Python\server\dvig.py

Comment: так не работает, нада чтобы папка была сменена до вызова скрипта

Comment: Где расположен `E:` диск? Локальный или сетевой (`net use`)?

Comment: `Е:` диск локальный